# Criar pasta em .bat com nome de variável

Tags: batch

Estou tentando criar pastas no meu DESKTOP de forma "automática" com o nome que eu colocar, quando o programa estiver rodando.

1° Preciso setar a quantidade de pastas(%number_of_agents%);

2° Entrar no caminho do meu DESKTOP e crio uma pasta(%Calls%) e entrar nesta pasta(cd Calls);

```
@echo off
::Type the numbers of PATHS that you want to create

set /p number_of_agents= "Type the number of agents: "
echo.
echo %number_of_agents%
echo.

cd %caminho_para_meu_desktop%
md "Calls"
cd Calls
```

3° Realizar um loop até a quantidade pré-determinada pela variável **number_of_agents**

```
::
for /l %%a in (1,1, %number_of_agents%) do 
(
set /p PA_login= "PA login: "
md "%PA_login%"
)
```

4° Quando dou o input da variável **PA_Login**, não eh possível criar a pasta com o nome

```
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seu código não tem nada de errado na lógica, é um **erro sintaxe** e a falta do uso do `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` para o `for` com `set`, no erro de sintaxe você quebrou uma linha após o `do` do teu `for` que não poderia ter quebrado, você fez isto:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1, %number_of_agents%) do
(
```

Quando deveria ser isto:

```
for /l %%a in (1,1, %number_of_agents%) do (
```

Se usar o `(` na linha seguinte o cmd não vai reconhecer como sequencia do comando, porque em CMD os parênteses são a maneira de passar a instrução como um bloco, mas a instrução precisa fazer parte do `for` e não estando na mesma linha não entenderá como tal, afinal BAT não é bem uma "linguagem de programação" como "outras", mas sim uma sequencia de comandos que aceita algumas sintaxes, veja o que ocorre com o seu script:

```
C:\>C:\Users\usuario\Desktop\a.bat

C:\>set number_of_agents=2
A sintaxe do comando está incorreta.
C:\>for /l %a in (1,1, 2) do
C:\>
```

Notou a mensagem `A sintaxe do comando está incorreta.`? Agora com o bloco (os parênteses) começando na mesma linha:

```
C:\>C:\Users\new_g\Desktop\a.bat

C:\>set number_of_agents=2

C:\>for /L %a in (1 1 2) do (echo %a )

C:\>(echo 1 )
1

C:\>(echo 2 )
2

C:\>pause
```

---

### Usando `set` dentro de um `for`

Para usar o `set` dentro do for será necessário habilitar o `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, veja um exemplo sem:

```
@echo off
set TESTE=0

for %%v in (1 2 3) do (
  set /p TESTE=Digite algo: 
  echo Resposta:  %TESTE%
)

pause
```

Ele sempre irá emitir "Resposta: 0" (zero, que é o valor inicial), então fazendo isto (troque os sinais `%%` por exclamações), ficando assim:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set COUNT=0

for %%v in (1 2 3 4) do (
  set /p TESTE=Digite algo: 
  echo Resposta: !TESTE!
)

pause
```

E ao final pode desabilitar com `SETLOCAL DisableDelayedExpansion`

**como é explicado em:** https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 1):

Tá um pouco confuso de entender a sua pergunta...

---

```bat
@echo off & title <nul & title .\%0 && set "number_of_agents="

:loop
set/p "-= Type the numbers of PATHS that you want to create: " 
set /p "number_of_agents= Type the number of agents: " && rem/

<con: echo/%number_of_agents%|findstr [0-9] && cd.||goto :loop

pushd "%userprofile%\desktop" && md .\Calls 2>nul &cd /d Calls

for /l %%a in (1 1 %number_of_agents%
)do set /p "PA_login=PA login: " && cmd /v/s/r md "!PA_login!"

tree /a /f . && popd && timeout -1 >nul & exit /b || goto :EOF
```

---

> - Código da resposta com comentários:
>
>   ---

```bat
rem :: habilita a inibição da saída dos comando na execução do bat
@echo off 

rem :: remove o titula da janela e atribui ao nome do arquivo bat
title <nul & title .\%0 

rem :: remove existente ou não a variável umber_of_agents
set "number_of_agents="

rem :: lable para verificar se o input contem ou não números
:loop

rem :: apenas uma forma de printar caracteres na tela sem quebrar  linha
set/p "-= Type the numbers of PATHS that you want to create: " 

rem :: seta variável number_of_agents e exibe o text entre "aspas"
set /p "number_of_agents= Type the number of agents: " && rem/

rem :: o mesmo que set /p e sem salvar valor/variável, mesmo que echo 
<con: echo/%number_of_agents%

rem :: procura na saída do comando anterior ocorrência 1+ números (também usado pra imprimir entrada na tela)
|findstr [0-9] 

rem :: usado para gerar quebra de linha caso encontrou número(s) na execução anterior 
&& cd.

rem :: se ação anterior (buscar números na variável %number_of_agents%) retorne falso, volta para label loop
||goto :loop

rem :: por a pasta atual salva para retornar (via popd) e traz para pila a pasta "%userprofile%\desktop"
pushd "%userprofile%\desktop"

rem :: caso a ação anterior retorne verdadeiro (traz para pila a pasta "%userprofile%\desktop") vai criar a pasta .\Call e entar nela, já ignorando a existência/saída de erro (mais rápido que usar if, n exist criar, if tem entra nela)
&& md .\Calls 2>nul & cd /d Calls

rem :: faz loop de 1 em 1 até o número informado na variável number_of_agents
for /l %%a in (1 1 %number_of_agents%)do 

rem :: imprimir na tela a entrada para PA_login e após a inserção do usuário, vai criar a pasta informado no input 
set /p "PA_login=PA login: " && cmd /v/s/r md "!PA_login!"

rem :: se o input foi executado, vai executar a ação de criae a pasta com o nome informado para variável PA_login
&& cmd /v/s/r md "!PA_login!"

rem :: vai listar as pasta criadas em formato de arvore (tree)
tree /a /f . 

rem :: retornar para a pasta onde originalmente (salvo por pushd) o bat foi executado
popd 

rem :: uma opção de pause, faz um timeout/pause, só aguardar entrada do teclado para continuar
timeout -1 
rem :: ai sair do bat, e para os mais paracônicos, se não sair vai para :eof (end of file|fim do arquivo)
&& exit /b || goto :EOF
```

---

**Obs.:** Foi o que entendi, se não for isso, use os comentários...